# SwiftUI: preferredColorScheme doesn't change status bar style

Tags: swiftui

For example, if the device is in dark mode and I set the color scheme to light with the code below, the status bar is invisible because it's still white and won't get updated until I do something like bring up the keyboard or trigger an action sheet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

This somehow works on my iPad but not on my iPhone or any of the simulators. And I couldn't find a way to change the status bar style with the SwiftUI App life cycle.

Am I missing something here? Does anyone have a solution for this?

[Screenshot of status bar not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2xjy.png)

Comment: I think it is a bug!

Comment: I'm unsure how to replicate this. I used your code with the `.preferredColorScheme(.light)`, and it doesn't look like the image attached, which is using the dark color scheme. The only noticeable thing is when starting the app, the status bar isn't visible because of white-on-white.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong screenshot which was using a light appearance and `.perferredColorScheme(.dark)`, but it's the same issue, the status bar isn't visible. I have edited the question with the correct screenshot.

Comment: Is ContentView the outer-most View of your app? If it is contained in another view, that view should probably have the modifier.

Comment: Should be a bug. I tried adding a new simulator and there doesn't seem to be an issue. But this problem still exists on my phone and some simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Try using environment modifier instead

```swift
.environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
```